# If condition does not work in Android Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing an issue where the if condition is not validated in android.

I have an UI (the same UI as in previous questions) where in when the user clicks the save button the details are stored in the sqlite database.

Here is the sample image of the UI:

[image]

For every task, I have an image associated based on the priority which I store in the `drawable` folder.

```
    EditText sd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sd);
    EditText desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description);
    Spinner type = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.type);
    Spinner priority = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.priority);
    int imageId = 0;
    if(priority.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Low"))
        imageId = R.drawable.blue;
    else if(priority.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("medium"))
        imageId = R.drawable.green;
    else
        imageId = R.drawable.red;
    Log.d("priority",priority.getSelectedItem().toString());
    String query = "insert into tasks values(null,'"+sd.getText()+"','"+type.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+priority.getSelectedItem().toString()+"','"+desc.getText()+"',CURRENT_DATE,"+imageId+");";
    db.execSQL(query);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

After inserting into the database, I switchover to another activity, where the details are displayed as a list.

This particular code:

```
if(priority.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Low"))
    imageId = R.drawable.blue;
else if(priority.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("medium"))
    imageId = R.drawable.green;
else
    imageId = R.drawable.red;
```

doesn't work. Because I get a deafult red image for all the tasks irrespective of the priority. Here `Log.d("priority",priority.getSelectedItem().toString());`, I wanted to check if the priority is selected properly, it displays **Low** but gives a red color which it shouldn't. Where I am doing the mistake?

Both `equals()` and `equalsIgnoreCase()` don't seem to work. Even `==` doesn't seem to work (I know it is wrong to use `==` to compare strings, but I wanted to give it a try).

**For reference:**
The statement I used to create the table is as follows:

```
String query = "create table if not exists tasks (id integer primary key autoincrement, shortdesc varchar not null, type varchar not null, priority varchar not null, desc varchar not null, taskdate date not null, imageid int not null);";
```

Even with Spinner Listener, it doesn't seem to work. Here  is the code:

```
priority.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(priority.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("low"))
                        imageId = R.drawable.blue;
                    else if(priority.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("medium"))
                        imageId = R.drawable.green;
                    else
                        imageId = R.drawable.red;
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

And the values from the log for the images,

```
04-22 06:42:01.414    2418-2418/com.app D/imageId﹕ 0
04-22 06:42:01.416    2418-2418/com.app D/red﹕ 2130837558
04-22 06:42:01.416    2418-2418/com.app D/blue﹕ 2130837555
04-22 06:54:30.795    1942-1942/com.app D/priority﹕ Low
```

The imageId I get is 0, but I am supposed to get one of the above values. The D/priority is the value from the spinner (`priority.getSelectedItem().toString()`). Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Print the imageId and compare with the R.drawable.xxx ids to be shure your if else construct workts. I think the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you update your code with the actual logs in it? To see the placements of the logs.
Have you tried with brackets for the if-else statements?

Comment: @RaphMclee I get this message in logcat (not as an error) `Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.` when I try to save it to database

Comment: That should not be the problem as the other entries in the DB do work as expected. Right?
Is the Red color the default value?
You write, that the imageId you get is 0. Is this after reading it from the DB or after the If-else?

Answer (score 0):

First add listeners for Spinner like this

```
priority.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
        String item = priority.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // do checking condition here
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(. I have tried. I have edited my question. Please see the update

Comment: show which values you are displaying in the spinner.. in the display it shows `Low` and in the code you are using `low`

Comment: I have used `equalsIgnoreCase()`. Should I use `equals()`?

Comment: first print this value `priority.getSelectedItem().toString()` are you getting correct value or not..show the logs

Comment: I get this message in logcat (not as an error) `Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.` when I try to save it to database

Comment: What are you doing man..it's a simple task... first you know android development minimum basics how to see logs and debugging and checking log values.. what i am asking what you are posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try implement this in your code:

```
      priority.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Low"))
                     imageId = R.drawable.blue;
                else if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals("Medium")) // you can use equalsIgnoreCase if you want.
                    imageId = R.drawable.green;
                else
                    imageId = R.drawable.red;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution :

```
String priortyStr = priority.getSelectedItem().toString();
int imageId = 0;
if(priortyStr.equals("Low"))
    imageId = R.drawable.blue;
else if(priortyStr.equals("Medium"))
    imageId = R.drawable.green;
else
    imageId = R.drawable.red;
```