# Spinner Listener not executed in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

As a continuation of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788579/if-condition-does-not-work-in-android-spinner/29790139#29790139), I found that the listener of the spinner is never executed (or) triggered and I am not able to solve the issue.

Here is the part of the code with the spinner and the listener:

```
Spinner priority = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.priority);

priority.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("listener","it works");
        Log.d("value",""+parent.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Low"));
        /*if(parent.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Low"))
            imageId = R.drawable.blue;
        else if(parent.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Medium"))
            imageId = R.drawable.green;
        else
            imageId = R.drawable.red;*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

In the log, the values of **listener** and **value** are not printed at all.

Comment: Did u added any item into that spinner??

Comment: Does the list is displayed with adapter? show its code.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code.

```
Spinner priority = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.priority);

priority.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.d("listener","it works");    
    //Instead of doing parent.getSelectedItem(), get the adapter from parent and from that adapter get item at position as below.
    Log.d("value",""+parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Low"));
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

   }
});
```

If your data is string then it will work else you are passing any custom object then you need to cast result from this `parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)` to that custom object class.

Comment: I get this message in logcat (not as an error) `Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.` when I try to save it to database

Comment: it may be something else, pl add your question n add full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution :

```
String priortyStr = priority.getSelectedItem().toString();
int imageId = 0;
if(priortyStr.equals("Low"))
    imageId = R.drawable.blue;
else if(priortyStr.equals("Medium"))
    imageId = R.drawable.green;
else
    imageId = R.drawable.red;
```